# Summing over probability distribution vs actual value

Tags: probability

A box containing 6 balls, 4 red and 2 black. How many balls should I draw without replacement such that I have drawn balls of both colour. By Pigeonhole principle the answer is 5 balls.

However, we could argue differently: THE first  two balls are of different
color has a probability of 8/15. Similarly, for the process of at least one ball of each colour to be completed after drawing three balls probability comes out to be 4/15. And for 4 balls, 2/15. For 5 balls 1/15. If we multiply these probabilities with the corresponding number of balls, we should get the value 5. After all that's what weighted average is: by summing over all variables multiplied by corresponding probability,  we're giving each individual case(number of balls) an importance according to its probability of occurring.  Instead we get the value 7.214 (approximately)

Where's the disparity?

Comment: Not sure what expected value has to do with this, but if you look at the probability that all balls are the same color for draws $k = 1, \dots$ you will see that it is $1, 8/15, 1/5, 1/15, 0$ and so by the fifth draw you will have balls of each color in agreement with the Pidgeonhole principle.

Comment: @Gregory I take it that expected value of a probability distribution takes all the different values of the variable and gives them weights or importances according  to the likelihood of their occurrence. The final result of adding them up should give the "certain" value, which is in this case 5— the number of draws at which point you're certain you've both colored balls. That's the intuition behind  probability,  is it not? To take into account all possible  outcomes scaled down by their likelihoods and adding them up should give a value which should  correspond  with certainty.

Comment: I don't think I agree with the intuition you have for expected value. For example take a rolling of a die labeled 1-6. The expected value is 3.5, of which I guarantee you - the roll will never appear with a 3.5 number. Nevertheless, that value is the mean value you will attempt by averaging.

What you describe would be the expected number of draws before you may see every color. It does not guarantee that the expected number of draws will match YOUR draw on a given trial.

Comment: @Gregory "What you describe would be the expected number of draws before you may see every color" Well, that certainly  clashes  with common sense: 7.214(expected value) is bigger 5( individual value of draws). If anything EV should  be smaller than that

Comment: Your probabilities are incorrect. The probability that you have one color after $k$ draws is $\{0, 7/15, 5/15, 2/15, 1/15, 0 \}$ your expected value is $14/5 = 2.8$.